# Libraries and approaches to have classifications on geo terms

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I am wondering if there is a library or an approach that can unify the geo terms for example:
USA is same as United states same as the US

Comment: I notice that you've tagged LUIS. Are you using LUIS?

Comment: yes am using luis for nlp

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily you can use the GeographyV2 prebuilt entity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-prebuilt-geographyv2

If what you really need is a way to look up information about a user-entered country in your database, the best way to do that is put the synonyms you want to recognize in the database itself. If you want to put the synonyms in LUIS then you can use a [list entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/reference-entity-list) but keep in mind that you will be limited in how long the list can be.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing same issue with geo places. For example.
USA, United states, United states of America, US.
Luis is able to detect them as built in entity of geographyV2
but I want NLP to pass all the similar terms of the user input. Ex user said US we send back geographyV2 entity and the similar synonyms of it , can luis do that by any chance? I'm desperate for this

Comment: You can create a list entity and provide synonyms for each item in the list. How many different places do you want to be able to recognize? Can you explain anything more about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want the ability for synonms generating. User input is USA , NLP detects correct entity but in the DB I have united states. so it would be nice if luis can pass the synonyms along with the user input

Comment: So you want to take a string that represents the name of a place and you want to get all other strings that refer to that same place by searching some online database? To what end? Do you want the user to say "USA" and have the bot reply back to the user with "United states, United states of America, US"? Are you building some kind of synonym bot? What does that have to do with LUIS? Please edit your question to actually explain what you're trying to do. Provide a sample conversation.

Comment: Hi @kyle , my App has info about population in countries. so if ur asking about USA population NLP will be able to detect the entity gepgraphyV2 perfectly/ BUt in the DB I have united states not USA. same for LA,UK,CA...etc. what i wnat is the nlp api to detect USA and send the matching synonys. example: USA, united staes of amireca. US..etc. so even if user asked for usa and i dont have a match for it in the db I know its synonms :)